# How to use my function for TextFormatting in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I wrote my `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter` but how can I use them in xaml?

Is there way to register `ICustomFormatter`? 
Ideally my `ICustomFormatter` should replace default currency formatter.

For example:

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,  StringFormat='{}{0:0.000 000}'}" />
```

How to set my function in `StringFormat`?

Comment: Why not use a converter to format the data?

Comment: In 15 years of .net development, I’ve never found it necessary to implement an `ICustomFormatter`.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want ```### ##0.000 000``` format for my currency.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, `IValueConverter` is really match convenient.

```
class PriceToString : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var number = System.Convert.ToDecimal( value );
        var integer = Math.Truncate( number );
        var fraction = number - integer;

        return integer.ToString( "N0" ) +
            NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator +
            Split( fraction, 6, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator );
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



    private static string Split(decimal fraction, int precision, string separator) {
        var src = fraction.ToString( "F" + precision ).Substring( 2 );

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) result.Append( separator );
            result.Append( src[i] );
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

}

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,  Converter='{StaticResource PriceToString}'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to override your current culture's number format settings to use `' '` as the group separator, then let the built-in formatter do the work for you:

```cs
public class CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter {
    [ThreadStatic] private static StringBuilder scratch;
    [ThreadStatic] private static NumberFormatInfo format;

    private StringBuilder Scratch => (scratch ?? (scratch = new StringBuilder()));

    private NumberFormatInfo Format {
        get {
            if (format != null)
                return format;

            var modifiedCulture = new CultureInfo(
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag,
                useUserOverride: true);

            modifiedCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
            format = modifiedCulture.NumberFormat;

            return format;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) {
        if (value is IFormattable f)
            return f.ToString("#,0.000 000", Format);

        return Scratch.Clear()
                      .AppendFormat(Format, "{0:#,0.000 000}", value)
                      .ToString();
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

This should also generate less garbage and be a bit more efficient.

Example results:

```cs
> new CurrencyConverter().Convert(1234567890.1234567890m, typeof(string), null, null)
"1 234 567 890.123 457"
```

Comment: My problem is that ```string.Format``` doesn't split into groups fractional part of number.